# How to open application to run code without showing activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, hide

I want when the user click on my application (when he open my application) the application run java without open the application or showing any activity.

Like [Fast Task killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.snowlife01.android.appkiller2) application.

And thanks.

Comment: update your question. doesn't make any meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create transparent activity for this

Here’s a complete file:

`res/values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then apply the style to your activity, for example:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I found another code too, and I use it because it is shorter than this. but thank you again for help